# Price always empty when create product programatically

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute

I am trying to create the product programatically,  like this:

```
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
 $data0['name'] = 'Gundamz';
 $data0['sku'] = 'Gundamz123';
 $data0['weight'] = 2;
 $data0['status'] = 1;
 $data0['attribute_set_id'] = 4;
 $data0['tax_class_id'] = 0;
 $data0['visibility'] = 4;
 $data0['description'] = 'Gundam Blade';
 $data0['short_description'] = "Authentic Gundam Blade";
 $data0['price'] = "20033.32";

 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
 $product->setTypeId('simple');
 $product->setAttributeSetId($dat['attribute_set_id']);
 $product->setData($data0);
 $product->save();
```

but the price and weight always empty after I save the product.

Any idea, how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Both weight and price are decimals with a scale of 4.

Most likely it's not working because you are inserting them as strings instead of decimals.
Try setting it by using:

```
 $product->setWeight(2.0000);
 $product->setPrice(20033.32);
```

In general it's better practice to use the setters instead of `setData()`.

Detailed article: http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/